# Linux "Volume group "c1" not found"

Tags: lvm

I want to add a disk my linux machine and extend my filesystem. I add a disk and create a partition using with fdisk. After I create physical volume with this partition. Right now I wanna add this pv in my volume manager but It's not work.

```
[root@cli ~]# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               cl
  PV Size               <19,00 GiB / not usable 3,00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              4863
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          4863
  PV UUID               mNhbwO-xfJI-nCrM-qNM1-7qpM-qvuQ-QSqJJX

  "/dev/sdb1" is a new physical volume of "<10,00 GiB"
  --- NEW Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name
  PV Size               <10,00 GiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               0
  Total PE              0
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               igRUC4-9K33-bsYd-MFh9-Xbpc-6IZf-JVonuo

[root@cli ~]# vgextend c1 /dev/sdb1
  Volume group "c1" not found
  Cannot process volume group c1


[root@cli ~]# vgs
  VG #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  cl   1   2   0 wz--n- <19,00g    0
[root@cli ~]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               cl
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <19,00 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              4863
  Alloc PE / Size       4863 / <19,00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               e9l6fH-0qND-m1vj-y9lQ-LgDR-pddA-F3Bnis

[root@cli ~]# vgdisplay c1
  Volume group "c1" not found
  Cannot process volume group c1
```

why can't I reach my own vg. what could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of you VG is `cl` with **L** (small), not with **1** (number one).

Comment: Sorry, I am very very blind :(